# Deadlock Risk in Nested Parallel For

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

Take the following naive implementation of a nested async loop using the ThreadPool:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(10, 10);
CountdownEvent icnt = new CountdownEvent(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    icnt.AddCount();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((inum) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i" + inum + " scheduled...");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);  // simulated i/o
        CountdownEvent jcnt = new CountdownEvent(1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        {
            jcnt.AddCount();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((jnum) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("j" + jnum + " scheduled...");
                Thread.Sleep(20000);  // simulated i/o
                jcnt.Signal();
                Console.WriteLine("j" + jnum + " complete.");
            }, j);
        }
        jcnt.Signal();
        jcnt.Wait();
        icnt.Signal();
        Console.WriteLine("i" + inum + " complete.");
    }, i);
}
icnt.Signal();
icnt.Wait();
```

Now, you'd never use this pattern (it will deadlock on start) but it does demonstrate a specific deadlock you can cause with the threadpool - by blocking while waiting for nested threads to complete after the blocking threads have consumed the entire pool.

I'm wondering if there's any potential risk of generating similarly detrimental behavior using the nested Parallel.For version of this:

```
Parallel.For(1, 50, (i) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("i" + i + " scheduled...");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);  // simulated i/o
    Parallel.For(1, 5, (j) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20000);  // simulated i/o
        Console.WriteLine("j" + j + " complete.");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("i" + i + " complete.");
});
```

Obviously the scheduling mechanism is far more sophisticated (and I haven't seen this version to deadlock at all), but the underlying risk seems like it may still be lurking there.  Is it theoretically possible to dry up the pool that the Parallel.For uses to the point of creating deadlock by having dependencies on nested threads? i.e. is there a limit to the number of threads that the Parallel.For keeps in it's back pocket for jobs that are scheduled after a delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no risk of a deadlock like that in `Parallel.For()` (or `Parallel.ForEach()`).

There are some factors that would lower the risk of deadlock (like dynamic count of threads used). But there is also a reason why the deadlock is impossible: the iteration is run on the original thread too. What that means is that if the `ThreadPool` is completely busy, the computation will run completely synchronously. In that case, you won't get any speedup from using `Parallel.For()`, but your code will still run, no deadlocks.

Also, a similar situation with `Task`s is also solved correctly: if you `Wait()` on a `Task` (or access its `Result`) that hasn't been scheduled yet, it will run inline in the current thread. I think this is primarily a performance optimization, but I think it could also avoid deadlocks in some specific cases.

But I think the question is more theoretical than practical. .Net 4 `ThreadPool` has default maximum thread count set to something like a thousand. And if you have thousand `Thread`s blocking at the same moment, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Yeah, in the former implementation, it'd be likely to exhibit only when you explicitly reduced the size of the pool (to reduce concurrent i/o ops or whatever). In the latter, I suppose you can adjust the concurrency separately for each loop using ParallelOptions, so it's something of a moot point either way.  Interesting to know that it runs in the main thread though.

Comment: WRT waiting on a task that hasn't been scheduled yet, I'm guessing that's with the assumption that the scheduler is fine with it running on that thread.  If a background thread does a Wait() on a task that needs to run on the UI thread, I would hope it wouldn't run it on that background thread :)

Comment: @JamesManning Yes, you're right. This is done by calling [`TryExecuteTaskInline()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449178.aspx) of the scheduler. And the scheduler can refuse to run the task inline by returning `false`.